# Acceder a un elemento que viene dentro de un array

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pude acceder al primero de image, pero ya no se como moverme en el otro árbol. mi código actual es:

```
 $datacategory = $this->Restaurant_mod->category(4);
        for($i=0;$i<count($datacategory);$i++){
            $datacategory[$i]['image'] = 'cambio de ruta';
        }
        $this->response($datacategory);
```

como puedo acceder al siguiente árbol y así sucesivamente ... Saludos!

Comment: Veo que realizas muchas preguntas respecto a codeigniter, pero jamas puntúas las respuestas ni las marcas como validas o como pregunta resulta a pesar de que se te dan las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo asi:

```
$datacategory = $this->Restaurant_mod->category(4);
    for($i=0;$i<count($datacategory);$i++){
        $datacategory[$i]['image'] = 'cambio de ruta';
        foreach($datacategory[$i]['products'] as $i => $product) {
            $product['image'] = 'notfound.png';
        }
    }
    $this->response($datacategory);
```

Comment: solo cambia el primero, tu sabes como quedaría el ciclo para acceder a esos sub elementos?

Comment: ya edite, intentalo asi

Comment: postman, se queda cargando, creo se creo un ciclo infinito no se...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago asi, por ejemplo si voy a mostrar la lista de productos o algo asi:
en mi index :

```
public function index()
{
   $data = array();
   $this->load->model("Modeloproducto");
   $this->data["productos"] = $this->Modeloproductos->mostrar();
   $this->load->view("paginas/lista_peliculas", $this->data);
}
```

En mi modelo de productos  "Modeloproducto"

```
function mostrar(){
  $this->db->from("Producto");
  $q = $this->db->get();
  return $q->result();
}
```

Y en mi vista:

```
<table>

 <thead>
   <tr>Encabezados de la tabla</tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <?php 
      foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        echo "<td>$producto->nombre</td>
              <td>$producto->descripcion</td>
              <td>
                <img src=\" " . base_url() . "/imagen/miniatura/$producto->imagen \">
              </td>
             ";

      }
 </tbody>

</table>
```

Si te funciona marca mi respuesta como la correcta.